# stick to top menu Gap

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, header, sticky

I'm using a js on my website (with wordpress) to get a stick to top menu when scrolling my page.
it works, when scrolling my header sticks on top, but there's a gap in my #entry content.
like on this example :
http://www.amsbooking.fr/mattieumoreau/artists/amine_edge_and_dance/

when scrolling and when my header sticks to top, the tittle "amine edge and dance" dissapears under the header, it is not fluid...
I guess there's a padding missing or something in my JS but I can't find why...

here is my css :

```
#stickyheader { width: 100%;padding-top:10px;top: 0;z-index: 1000;padding-bottom: 10px;line-height: 24px;position:relative;background-color: #f8f8f8;}
#unstickyheader {height:auto;}
```

and my JS :

```
$(function () {
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('#stickyheader').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0px'
            });
            $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
        }else{
            $('#stickyheader').css({
                position: 'relative'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

here is jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/2UCH4/

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are setting that element with `position:fixed` the space that was fill by the element is now available and the next container just switch up. To fix that you can correct the space with `margin-top`:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
     $('#stickyheader').css({
         position: 'fixed',
         top: '0px'
     });
     $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
         var mT = $('#stickyheader').css('height'); /*Add this*/
         $('#stickyheader').next('.post').css('marginTop', mT); /*Add this*/
  }else{
     $('#stickyheader').css({
         position: 'relative'
     });
     $('#stickyheader').next('.post').css('marginTop', '0'); /*Add this*/
 }
});
```

Check this **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2UCH4/2/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Np mate glad to help you @user2882154

Comment: hum @Danko... I checked on other pages and I still have the problem... can you pease have a look ? http://www.amsbooking.fr/mattieumoreau/booking-request/
strange ?

Comment: First at all check you are loading the script function for all pages and also check i'm using the classname `.post` to set the margin top so the next container need to have that classname. You can make a fake class in all your pages @user2882154

Comment: the script is loaded on all pages, I've checked... but I don't undersant what you mean by using the classname .post ? do I need to add into my stylesheet ?

Comment: @user2882154 not in your stylesheet if you see the page on the fiddle has a container next to the stickyheader with class post. In the function i'm reference that with `.next('.post').css` in the other page you post here you don't have that class then doesn't work

Comment: ok I understand. I'll add the <div class="post"> on pages where it's missing... I'll let you know, thanks again

Comment: it works thanks a lot. what if I would like to add 10px padding top to my post when the header is sticked on top ?

Comment: add that on the else css

Comment: where ? in the js ? Can't find... I juste want it to be more fluid

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45211/discussion-between-danko-and-user2882154)